# increase width of AcroFields(iTextSharp)

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to populate the data to PDF Templates, which is created in OpenOffice. it populating fine, I'm getting proper PDF, but some where i want to increase the width of the AcroField.

I did below code. it is increasing the width but text is not displaying.

```
AcroFields.Item fldItem = fields.getFieldItem(fieldName);
for (int i =0; i < fldItem.size(); ++i) {
  PdfDictionary widgetDict = fldItem.getWidget(0);
  PdfArray rectArr = widgetDict.getAsArray(PdfName.RECT); 
  float origX = rectArr.getAsNumber(0).floatValue();
  rectArr.set( 2, new PdfNumber( origX + 12 + 60 ) );
}
```

in the below image highlighted one. actual string is `10000     SUPERIOROPTICAL 123 4567 89` 
[image]

please help.
thanks.

Comment: Please do not invite me to chat unless you're a customer.

Comment: Hey, I tried your code and it works perfectly. But I also need to increase the height, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem. I've made this POC: [ChangeFieldSize](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/ChangeFieldSize)

In this example, I take a form with three fields, among others a `"Name"` and a `"Company"` field. I *first* change the size of the `"Name"` field, the same way you change the field. Then I fill out the `"Name"` field and the `"Company"` field. Note that the order in which I perform these operations is important. Maybe you're doing it the other way round.

The result looks like [this](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/field_changed.pdf):
[image]

As you can see, the text isn't truncated the way it is in your screen shot.

So there are two things you can try:

- change the order in which you change the field rectangle and fill out the field.
- upgrade to the most recent version of iTextSharp.

If that doesn't help, post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Sorry for invited chat. thanks for your best answer. the change is
`float origX = rectArr.getAsNumber(2).floatValue();
rectArr.set( 2, new PdfNumber( origX + 20f ) );`

Comment: Aha, now I see it. You have the wrong index. I overlooked that when I made my example. In any case, I'm glad you were able to solve the problem.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Is it possible to increase the height of the fields as well ? When increasing the height, the fields below it need to move down as well.

Comment: Your request is incompatible with the nature of AcroForm fields. AcroForm technology is not designed to meet your requirement. Please study ISO-32000 to discover the error in your request.