# Dynamically changing field size in a pdf form using itext

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I am using PDFStamper to populate a PDF form file. The PDF form has labels and a fields where you can enter values. The size of this field is fixed and when I try to input values into it programmatically, it chops off all data which overshoots the size of these fields. Is there a way to change the size of the fields when populating them using the java APIs ?

P.S. setting the form flatterning to false does not help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [increase width of AcroFields(iTextSharp)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404413/increase-width-of-acrofieldsitextsharp)

Comment: Another way is to set the font size to auto (0) and if the 'donotscroll' flag is set - remove it.