# How to increase Form field width/height through code in C#?

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-form

I have multiline text form field in pdf template. I am dispaying text from database; when the text is large form field accepts some text and the other is cut off. How can I increase form field width/height at runtime?

```
foreach (string field in _pdfStamper.AcroFields.Fields.Keys)
{
    if (field.StartsWith("FreeAnswer", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        TextPart tp = new TextPart();
        tp.LeftMargin = 5;
        tp.RightMargin = 5;
        tp.Text = answers[(openQuestionPages * 3) + add];
        _fillText(field, new List<TextPart>() { tp });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [increase width of AcroFields(iTextSharp)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404413/increase-width-of-acrofieldsitextsharp). Note that increasing the size of an AcroForm field doesn't mean the rest of the content will move. If that's what you expect, some of your assumptions about the Portable Document Format are wrong.

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie so what should i do in this situation?? i also want to move the other contents.

Comment: Your question proves my point: you don't know what PDF is about. If your form is based on AcroForm technology, you are asking something that is impossible (in general, not limited to iTextSharp). Have you considered using XFA (the XML Forms Architecture)? That's XML wrapped inside PDF. Pure XFA forms are dynamic by nature. AcroForms are static.